# Highchart : custom x gridLine and zIndex of series

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts

I'm trying to implement a custom x `gridline` for my HighChart graphic (external at HighChart). The line appears well, but is above my curves.

[image: Line above my curves]

Here is my `css` class for my custom `gridline`: (I tried reducing the zIndex, but I get the same behavior.)

```
.line-x-axis {
     height: 420px;
     width: 1px;
     border-color: #eeeeee;
     position: absolute;
     z-index: 0 !important;
     background-color: #eeeeee;
     bottom: 0;
     top: 43px;
     left: 0;
}
```

How can i, change the `zIndex` of all my curve ? It is possible ?

Comment: How do you create such gridLine? If it's HTML, then it's not possible. Highcharts are using SVG/VML, so HTML tags can be or under, or over the SVG container. Anyway, why don't you use `plotLines` from Highcharts or `chart.renderer.path()` to draw paths on a chart?

Comment: please create a fiddle of your code !

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I resolved my problem. I managed with `z-index` and set a transparent `background-color` to my HighCharts container.
@Pawel, thank you for this alternative.